# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on face-api import

Tags: javascript, node.js, face-api, facial-identification

I'm trying to make a simple demo application to use face-api. Line 2 of my code is throwing this error when I attempt to import the face-api.min.js file.

I've tried reformatting the import but I haven't been able to get it working.

```
//Importing Face Detection API
import faceapi from "./face-api.min.js";
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: `import` is just not supported in NodeJS.

Comment: I'd assume some kind of TS compliler is used there.

Comment: @clarity nah, TS would throw compile time errors then. Not sure what environment is used, it isn't plain NodeJS though as that would throw a different error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [package documentation](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js?files=1#face-apijs-for-nodejs) says, the correct way to import it is

```
import * as faceapi from 'face-api.js';
```

EDIT: For usage in Node.js with CommonJS imports you can do:

```
const faceapi = require('face-api.js');
```